# What's the preferred way to create a String from a literal?

Tags: rust

Is there a performance or stylistic reason to prefer one of the following forms for creating a String from a literal in Rust?

```
"hello world".to_string()
format!("hello world")
String::from("hello world")
```

Comment: At the very least, avoid `format!`, because the formatting machinery is heavy weight for such a straightforward translation.

Comment: **Reminder to all would be answerers**: StackOverflow is not a forum and thus is not about *debating*; answers should strive for **objectivity** and be backing by authoritative references (such as the official style guide or a core developer's opinion).

Comment: @MatthieuM. to_string() also uses the formatting machinery.

Comment: @fjh: Ah yes, in the absence of specialization it's probably unavoidable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic way in the Rust compiler internals and thus Rust in general is to use [`to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string). It is done this way in the compiler and backed by Alex Crichton in three pull requests ([1](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/29618#issuecomment-154122416), [2](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/26176#issuecomment-110813608), [3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19708#issuecomment-66509110)) that tried to change this.

The argument is that `to_string` most clearly defines what you want. Performance-wise both `to_string` and `format!` are slower than `String::from`. But once we get impl specialization there's a good chance that they will perform exactly the same.

---

That said, [clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy) lints against `"abc".to_string()` and suggests `"abc".to_owned()`.

Comment: Exact link to clippy's warning (with rationale): https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/wiki#str_to_string

Comment: Interesting. The [String documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html) uses `String::from` in most of the examples. I wonder if that should be changed if `to_string` is the preferred approach.

Comment: @JimmyCuadra I don't think it should. `to_string` is one core developer's preferred method, not _the_ preferred approach. There are performance arguments against it (see e.g. [this](https://github.com/shepmaster/sxd-document/commit/4f29dee8ee4e98653b10778fb660ddc76f5debc6)), and I don't really by the argument that `to_string` is clearer than `String::from`.

Comment: @JimmyCuadra: I actually do not find it strange; in documentation you want to focus on the API at hand and therefore using extraneous functions/types may be distracting (users will wonder where they come from). That being said, if you follow the link (1) from ker you will see that others seem to have switched to using `String::from` too, finding it conveniently explicit and performing well. Of course, it can be argued that it is better to focus on more general purpose methods, especially as specialization should take care of the performance aspect.

Comment: I prefer `String::from` for literals, and `to_string()` for non-literals, so that's probably why newer docs have String::from().

Comment: that's a sensible middle way. maybe the clippy lint could be adjusted to detect literal vs `&str`